# Collapsing UIView when using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

What is the easiest (and generic) way to hide a UIView when using Autolayout?

In my view I add UIScrollView so that it fills the whole screen and then I add my CustomUIViews that contain other views like buttons, labels etc.

I know the trick where you just set height constant to 0 and the view seems to be hidden - and that would be just perfect for me. There is only one *but*. When I set height to 0 on my CustomUIViews, I get lots of auto layout warning, because UIViews inside also have some height and spacing constraints.

Is there a nice trick to do what I want?

Comment: Can removing and adding the custom view again work for you?

Comment: It could, but then I would have to remove and add constraints on surrounding views - this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: what do you mean by surrounding views?

Comment: Lets say that I have 3 views ViewA, ViewB, ViewC. They are layed out vertically and they fill screen horizontally. ViewA is constrained to top of the screen, ViewB is constrained to bottom of ViewA, ViewC to bottom of ViewB. And now I want to hide ViewB, so I would have to fix constrains on ViewC.

Comment: There is one way you can achieve the desired result which as follows,

once you set the view's height to 0, you have to deactivate the view's subview constraints by setting NSLayoutConstraints's active property and then you'll not receive any auto layout's warning. However you need to create outlets for all other constraints on which you can enumerate and deactivate it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wish I could accept your comment ;)

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: I personally only use autolayout to center text in subviews. It is the ONLY thing that it saves time in, compared to writing out frame math (20 seconds vs half an hr setting up constraints)

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved this by now, but set one for C's top attaching to A's lower and make it a lower priority than another that attaches C's top to B's lower. Then hide/show.